# "No matching bean of type found for dependency" after I moved some classes

Tags: java, spring

I'm dealing with an application composed of many projects. I moved some classes from a project to another one, but I get some unit tests failures.

The most frequent error is like following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    [cut]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prexStatisticsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.companyname.kernel.package1.dao.StatisticsDao com.companyname.kernel.package2.service.PrexStatisticsService.statisticsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [it.companyname.kernel.package1.dao.StatisticsDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    [cut]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.companyname.kernel.package1.dao.StatisticsDao com.companyname.kernel.package2.service.PrexStatisticsService.statisticsDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [it.companyname.kernel.package1.dao.StatisticsDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [it.companyname.kernel.package1.dao.StatisticsDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:952)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 41 more
```

I don't understand what happened, there're only annotated classes, there isn't xml configuration files. Any help, please?

**Updated:**

I've modified a unit test method, replacing all its content with a single line:

```
assertEquals(1, 1);
```

And it still fails. I understand now that Spring can't start when I run unit tests, but it can run when I launch the application (I don't know why).

Comment: Could be the classes are out of package scan after the moving. So spring cannot find them

Comment: it clearly says that it.companyname.kernel.package1.dao.StatisticsDao is not found. As you might have moved it to other project. Component scanning unable to find it.

Comment: Thanks for replies, I've modified a unit test (please see my updated question) and it still fails. I know that its a configuration problem, but I can't fix it. How can I tell to Spring where are the classes?